# Diff between local and remote directory

Tags: directory, rsync, diff

I want to compare my local directory and remote directory.

Example: Consider 2 directories as local and remote directory

```
|-local
|  |--aaa
|  |   |--file1
|  |   |--file2
|  |
|  |--bbb
|  |   |--file1
|  |   |--file2
|  |-file1
|
|-remote
   |--ddd
       |--file1
       |--file2
```

If I try running rsync

```
rsync -avcn local/ remote/
```

I am getting following output

```
./
file1
aaa/
aaa/file1
aaa/file2
bbb/
bbb/file1
bbb/file2
```

Is there a way where I can only get folder name if all the files are also missing from local

Excepted output:

```
file1
aaa/
bbb/
```

Here file1 and file2 both are present in "aaa" and "bbb", so only folder name should be visible in output.

Comment: Please replace your screenshots with plain text. They are easier to read, take less space, can be searched, and copy/pasted.

Comment: @Sparhawk I have updated the post. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks @Vineet. However, I think you have typos now. Where did `ccc` come from? It's not in the first code block. Did you mean `bbb`? Also, the output of `rsync` contains `./`. By your logic, doesn't that also contain everything else?

Comment: @Sparhawk I am really sorry about this. I have update again.

Comment: Vineet, did my answer help at all?

Comment: Not clear if you want a CLI utility or just some way to tell the differences. If you want some GUI utility and have SSH/SFP access, `kdiff3` does a remarkable job.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your command into the following awk script.

```
$ rsync -avcn local/ remote/ | awk 'BEGIN {prev="./"} substr($0, 0, (length(prev))) != prev {print $0; prev = $0}'
file1
aaa/
bbb/
```

### Explanation

- `{prev="./"}`: before we start reading the input, set the variable `prev` to `./` (which is the first line of the output). From here, we will use this variable to store the contents of the previous line.
- `substr($0, 0, (length(prev)))`: extract a `substr`ing of the whole line `$0`, starting at the first character `0`, and with length as long as the previous line `(length(prev))`.
- `!= prev`: compare the substring of the current line to the previous line. Essentially, this tests if the current line (the substring) starts with the string from the previous line. We don't use a simple regex here (anchored to the beginning of the line), because we'd have to escape it.
- `{print $0; prev = $0}`: if the current line *does* start with the previous line, then ignore it (i.e. don't print it), if it *doesn't* match, then it's a new directory, so print that whole line `print $0`, and store the fresh line in the `prev` variable `prev = $0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, I Reckon, is using `find <dir> -maxdepth 1 -type d` against the 2 directories, then compare the sorted results. Similarly to Paul T's solution but with a depth limit and considering directories only:

```
$ cd <local_folder>; find . -type d -maxdepth 1 | sort > ~/local-list.txt
$ cd <remote_folder>; find . -type d -maxdepth 1 | sort > ~/remote-list.txt
$ diff -u ~/remote-list.txt ~/local-list.txt
```